# How can attach new EBS volume to existing EC2 instance using java sdk?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have tried using AttachVolumeRequest but in response i get following error

```
 Caught Exception: The request must contain the parameter volume
 Reponse Status Code: 400
 Error Code: MissingParameter
```

here is my code , in this code ec2 is my amazonclient object and its work fine so far

```
AttachVolumeRequest attachRequest=new AttachVolumeRequest()
    .withInstanceId("my instance id");
attachRequest.setRequestCredentials(credentials);

EbsBlockDevice ebs=new EbsBlockDevice();
ebs.setVolumeSize(2);

//attachRequest.withVolumeId(ebs.getSnapshotId());

AttachVolumeResult result=ec2.attachVolume(attachRequest);
```

any help is highly appreciated. thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Cause

Class [EbsBlockDevice](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/EbsBlockDevice.html) from the [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/) serves a different purpose, accordingly method [getSnapshotId()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/EbsBlockDevice.html#getSnapshotId%28%29) only returns *The ID of the snapshot from which the volume will be created*, i.e. not the volume ID, hence the respective exception.

### Solution

You most likely want to use class [CreateVolumeRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/CreateVolumeRequest.html) instead, e.g. (from the top of my head):

```
CreateVolumeRequest createVolumeRequest = new CreateVolumeRequest()
    .withAvailabilityZone("my instance's AZ") // The AZ in which to create the volume.
    .withSize(2); // The size of the volume, in gigabytes.

CreateVolumeResult createVolumeResult = ec2.createVolume(createVolumeRequest);

AttachVolumeRequest attachRequest = new AttachVolumeRequest()
    .withInstanceId("my instance id");
    .withVolumeId(createVolumeResult.getVolume().getVolumeId());

AttachVolumeResult attachResult = ec2.attachVolume(attachRequest);
```