# Amazon AWS creating EBS(Elastic block storage) through Java API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to find a way to create a new EBS and attach it to a running instance pro grammatically through the AWSJavaSDK. I see ways to do this with command line tools and with rest based calls but no way through the SDK proper.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can attach new EBS volume to existing EC2 instance using java sdk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953587/how-can-attach-new-ebs-volume-to-existing-ec2-instance-using-java-sdk)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use [createVolume](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html#createVolume%28com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.CreateVolumeRequest%29) to create the item.  That looks to return a [CreateVolumeResult](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/CreateVolumeResult.html), which has a `Volume` object inside.

You would then take the `Volume` returned from the `createVolume` call and [attachVolume](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html#attachVolume%28com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.AttachVolumeRequest%29) with a matching [AttachVolumeRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/AttachVolumeRequest.html).

This is all done after you create one of AWS `AmazonEC2Client` objects: [documentation is all pulled from here.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html)

Workflow of the code would probably look like this (note: pseudo code is used and there may be a few more pieces to hook in but the workflow should look something like this)

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new AWSCredentials();
AmazonEC2Client client = new AmazonEC2Client(credentials);
CreateVolumeResult request = new  CreateVolumeRequest(java.lang.Integer size,
                       java.lang.String availabilityZone);
CreateVolumeResponse volumeResponse = client.createVolume(request);
AttachVolumeRequest attachRequest = new AttachVolumeRequest(volumeResponse.getVolume().getVolumeId(),  java.lang.String instanceId, java.lang.String device);
client.attachVolume(attachRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the following code to create the EBS volumes using java API.

```
public void createVolume(String instanceId){
    System.out.println("Creating the volume begins...");
    CreateVolumeRequest  creq = new CreateVolumeRequest(50, "us-west-2a");
    CreateVolumeResult cres =  ec2.createVolume(creq);

     // Create the list of tags we want to create
    System.out.println("Setting the tags to the volume...");
    ArrayList<Tag> instanceTags = new ArrayList<Tag>();
    instanceTags.add(new Tag("Name","Sachin"));
    CreateTagsRequest createTagsRequest = new CreateTagsRequest().withTags(instanceTags).withResources(cres.getVolume().getVolumeId());
    ec2.createTags(createTagsRequest);
    System.out.println("Attaching the volume to the instance....");
    AttachVolumeRequest areq = new AttachVolumeRequest(cres.getVolume().getVolumeId(),instanceId, "/dev/sdh");
    AttachVolumeResult ares = ec2.attachVolume(areq);
    System.out.println("Creating the volume ends...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `CreateVolumeRequest` object in the api to create your request
and see the result in the returning `CreateVolumeResponce` object
as instructed [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-CreateVolume.html)