# AWS for Java SDK create EBS Volume and write data to it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I have to achieve below thing programmatically through AWS Java SDK .

1. Create an EBS volume
2. Upload data to it
3. This EBS volume will not be attached to EC2 instance but AWS lambda will read data from it

I have seen example where we can create an EBS volume and attach to EC2 instance [Amazon AWS creating EBS(Elastic block storage) through Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178175/amazon-aws-creating-ebselastic-block-storage-through-java-api/16178272)

But it is not showing how to write data to EBS volume.

Can anybody please help me in how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

The EC2 Client API has a [method](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/ec2/Ec2Client.html#createVolume-software.amazon.awssdk.services.ec2.model.CreateVolumeRequest-) that lets you create an EBS volume. Here is the V2 example:

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ec2.Ec2Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ec2.model.*;


/**
 * To run this Java V2 code example, ensure that you have setup your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 * 
 */
public class CreateVolume {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        Ec2Client ec2 = Ec2Client.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        try {
            CreateVolumeRequest request = CreateVolumeRequest.builder()
                 .availabilityZone("us-east-1e")
                .size(384)
                .volumeType(VolumeType.GP3)
                .build();

            CreateVolumeResponse response = ec2.createVolume(request);
            System.out.println("The ARN is "+response.outpostArn());
            ec2.close();

        } catch (Ec2Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

However, **Ec2Client** does not have a method that lets you write data to an an EBS volume. For information about storing data, see this doc.

https://angus.readthedocs.io/en/2014/amazon/setting-up-an-ebs-volume.html

If you have a business requirement to dynamically store/read data using a Lambda function, why not use an Amazon S3 bucket. The S3 Java API exposes methods that makes it very easy to read and write data.

Comment: Thanks @smac2020. We are using EBS because the file stored in EBS is nothing but in memory database file . We will use lambda then to read data from this in memory database created in EBS volume